# Recover Windows after Ubuntu Install

Tags: boot, windows, grub2

Hi I have installed Windows xp and after that i got disk error while installing Ubuntu so I installed using new CD Disk now after successful installation of Ubuntu I didn't get grub menu it straightaway goes to Ubuntu without showing windows list.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Start your computer with a Ubuntu Live CD
Step 2: Find your linux partition by typing `sudo fdisk -l`
Step 3: Mount the Linux Partition `sudo mount /dev/nameofpartition /mnt`
 
Step 4: Install GRUB `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda`
 
Step 5: update GRUB - `sudo update-grub`

I think this could resolve your problem.